Current Status of MOSAIC
MOSAIC (Modernization of Special Airworthiness Certification) is a cluster of proposed FAA rule changes that would broaden the aircraft eligible to be operated by a pilot with a Sport License. In July of 2023 they issued a Notice of Proposed Rulemaking (NPRM), the initial step in the promulgation of new regulations.
The comment period (typically 30-60 days) was extended to the end of January, 2024 and is now closed.
It has now been six months since.  I'm accustomed (as a policy scholar) to final rules being produced within 30-90 days of the closure of comment periods, with rules going into effect 30-90 days after publication of the final.
What is the current status of MOSAIC, when should we expect a final rule to be published, and did I miss a confirmation notice being published somewhere?

MOSAIC received a lot more public feedback than many NPRMs, so it is not surprising that it is taking longer.
As far as I know, no timeline for the final rule has been announced publicly. A spokesman for the EAA has claimed that people at the FAA told him in conversations that they expect a final rule in early to mid 2025.
The FAA reauthorization act mandates that the final rule be issued no later than 24 months after the passage of that bill. That bill was passed on May 16, 2024, which puts a hard deadline of May 16, 2026 for the MOSAIC final rule. But hopefully it's earlier!
